# How to get select option value React

Tags: reactjs, input, fetch, html-select

I need a little help with my project. I think it is almost done, but I don't know how to finish...

So, I want to build app with input, select and button. Into input u can write for example, mettalica and after click on button app renders list with all songs, titles and tabTypes(guitar tabs). The problem is that i want to get info from select and render only that songs which includes for example player tabs.

Sandbox Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-ys6py?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
class Search extends React.Component {
  state = {
    searchValue: "",
    songs: [],
    musicTabs: [
      'Dowolne',
      'Bass',
      'Player',
      'Chords',
      'Guitar'
    ],
    result: ''
  };

  handleOnChange = event => {
    this.setState({ searchValue: event.target.value });
  };

  handleSelectChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      result: event.target.value
    })
    console.log(this.state.result)
  }

  handleSearch = () => {
    this.makeApiCall(this.state.searchValue);
  };

  makeApiCall = async searchInput => {
    let api_url = `https://www.songsterr.com/a/ra/songs/byartists.json?artists=${searchInput}`;
    const response = await fetch(api_url);
    const songs = await response.json();
    this.setState({ songs });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <input
          name="text"
          type="search"
          placeholder="Search..."
          onChange={event => this.handleOnChange(event)}
          value={this.state.SearchValue}
        />

        <Select optionValue={ this.state.musicTabs } change={ this.handleSelectChange } value={ this.state.result } />

        <br />
        <button onClick={this.handleSearch}>Search</button>


        {this.state.songs ? (
          <div>
            {
              this.state.songs.map((song, index) => (
                <div key={index} className="lists">
                  <h1>Artist: <span>{song.artist.name}</span></h1>
                  <h2>Song title: <span>{song.title}</span></h2>
                  <ol>
                    <b>Available tabs:</b>
                    {song.tabTypes.map((tab, index) =>
                      <li key={index}> {song.tabTypes[index]} </li>
                    )}

                  </ol>

                </div>
              ))


            }
          </div>
        ) : (
            <p>Something</p>
          )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}



const Select = (props) => {
  const { optionValue, change } = props;

  const valueMusicTabs = optionValue.map((musicTab, index) => {
   return <option name={ optionValue[index] } key={ index }> { optionValue[index] } </option>
  })

  return (

    <>
    <select onChange={ change }>
      { valueMusicTabs } 

    </select>

  </>

  )
};
```

Thanks for help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the codesandbox, everything was working right. `this.setState` is an asynchronous function. So, if you will `console.log` after `this.setState` chances are your will not log updated value. You can do it like this with a callback function.

```
handleSelectChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      result: event.target.value
    }, () => console.log(this.state.result))
  }
```

If you want to `filter` you can do that by making a function like:

```
filterSongs = selected => {
 return songs.filter(song => song.tabTypes === selected);
}
```

and After that modify your `handleSelectChange` as:

```
handleSelectChange = (event) => {
    let songs = filterSongs(event.target.value);
    this.setState({
      result: event.target.value,
      toDisplay: songs
    }, () => console.log(this.state.result))
  }
```

and finally in your `JSX`:

```
return (
  <>
    {toDisplay.map((song, index) => {
      return <p key={index}>{song.toString()}</p>
    })}
  </>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! I have last question, where I have to use method to filter that rendered list. If I select "Player" I want to render only that songs, which inlcudes "Player" tab in tabTypes. I still can't get it. I can't do it by changing API link.

Comment: @tomsoon95 Answer Updated

Comment: Where exactly I have to modify my JSX?

Comment: Could You please modify this in SandBox?

Answer (score 1):

I think you did everything right, just used the wrong `prop`

```
<Select optionValue={ this.state.musicTabs } onChange={ this.handleSelectChange } value={ this.state.result } />
```

the `change` prop on the `Select` component should just be changed to `onChange` since it's a default event it will be passed with the event to your `handleChange` method

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly. you want to get the results from API based on selected values of `input` and `select`.

as I can see you are only passing the param from input nothing from select.

```
  handleSearch = () => {
    this.makeApiCall(this.state.searchValue);
  };

  makeApiCall = async searchInput => {
    let api_url = `https://www.songsterr.com/a/ra/songs/byartists.json?artists=${searchInput}`;
    const response = await fetch(api_url);
    const songs = await response.json();
    this.setState({ songs });
  };
```

The new call will be

```
let api_url = `https://www.songsterr.com/a/ra/songs/byartists.json?artists=${searchInput}&tabTypes=${selectValue}`;
```

I do not know how what are the parameters this API accepts.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers! I have last question, where I have to use method to filter that rendered list. If I select "Player" I want to render only that songs, which inlcudes "Player" tab in tabTypes. I still can't get it. I can't do it by changing API link.